# iOS: changing NSString value

Tags: ios, nsstring

Will this bit of code produce any memory leaks? Is it the correct way to change NSString values?

```
NSString * enemiesAndElementsTextureFileName = @"bla bla";
enemiesAndElementsTextureFileName = @"bl";
```

Comment: You should use `NSMutableString`.

Comment: It won't produce memory leak. It is valid code and is a very common usage, so you might want to clarify yourself why you doubt anything could go wrong with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That way of doing it won't cause any memory leaks and it is indeed correct. In this case you wouldn't need an `NSMutableString` because you aren't altering the string literal itself, you are simply replacing the string value with a new one (replacing @"bla bla" with @"bl").

In this case, however, your string will now be 'bl', so you can delete that first line value and just have `NSString * enemiesAndElementsTextureFileName = @"bl";`

Answer (score 1):

Yes NSString allocated once. This is one of the way

Comment: ...are you saying "yes is correct" or "yes it will produce memory leaks"? I assume the first option. So the previous string will not be leaked in memory somewhere ?

Comment: Even if it was not allocated, literal @"foo" is literally equal to `[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"foo"];`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use NSMutableString with the following method as your needs:

```
// Allocate  
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:10];  
// set string content  
[str setString:@"1234"];  

// Append  
[str appendString:@"567"];  

// Concat  
[str appendFormat:@"age is %i and height is %.2f", 27, 1.55f];  

// Replace 
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"height"];//查找字符串height的位置  
[str replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@"no"];  

// Insert  
[str insertString:@"abc" atIndex:2];  

// Delete  
range = [str rangeOfString:@"age"];  
[str deleteCharactersInRange:range];  
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```